# Implementing BiLSTM-Attention-CRF Model using Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, named-entity-recognition, attention-model

I am trying to Implement the BiLSTM-Attention-CRF model for the NER task. I am able to perform NER tasks based on the BILSTM-CRF model (code from [here](https://github.com/jayavardhanr/End-to-end-Sequence-Labeling-via-Bi-directional-LSTM-CNNs-CRF-Tutorial/blob/master/Named_Entity_Recognition-LSTM-CNN-CRF-Tutorial.ipynb)) but I need to add attention to improve the performance of the model.

Right now my model is :

BiLSTM  -> Linear Layer (Hidden to tag) -> CRf Layer

The Output from the Linear layer is (seq. length x tagset size) and it is then fed into the CRF layer.

I am trying to replace the Linear layer with Attention layer using the code below:

```
class SelfAttention(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, hidden_dim):
            super().__init__()
            self.hidden_dim = hidden_dim
            self.projection = nn.Sequential(
                    nn.Linear(hidden_dim, 64),
                    nn.ReLU(True),
                    nn.Linear(64, 1)
            )

    def forward(self, encoder_outputs):
            batch_size = encoder_outputs.size(0)
            # (B, L, H) -> (B , L, 1)
            energy = self.projection(encoder_outputs)
            weights = F.softmax(energy.squeeze(-1), dim=1)
            # (B, L, H) * (B, L, 1) -> (B, H)
            outputs = (encoder_outputs * weights.unsqueeze(-1)).sum(dim=1)
            return outputs, weights
```

While doing so I have two issues:

- I can not make it work so that the output should come in the shape of (seq. length x tagset size) so that it can be fed into CRF Layer.
- According to this [paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/stamp/stamp.jsp?arnumber=8922599), we need to initialize and learn word-level context vector which I can not see in this implementation of the attention model.

Kindly help me out.

TIA

Answer (score 1):

What you implemented is a quite unusual type of self-attention. It resembles [the original self-attention for sequence classification](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.03130.pdf) which was probably a partial inspiration for the [Attention is all you need](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/2017/file/3f5ee243547dee91fbd053c1c4a845aa-Paper.pdf) paper.

In general, attention can be understood as a sort of probabilistic hidden state retrieval. Given some keys, you retrieve some values. In the standard [Bahdanau's attention](https://arxiv.org/abs/1409.0473), the key is the decoder state and the values are the encoder states. In Transformer self-attention, are used as keys to retrieve some information from other states, i.e., every state is a key and a value at the same time. In the special case, you have implemented, you only have one key that is sort of encrypted in the `projection`. You use this single constant key to retrieve a vector from the hidden states, as a result, you only get one vector per sequence.

What you probably want to is using the Transformer-style self-attention where each state is used as a key a gets a summary of values. For that, you can use the [`nn.MultiheadAttention` class](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.MultiheadAttention.html) in PyTorch. In addition to what I described, it does the attention in multiple heads, so it can do a more fine-grained retrieval. Note that in your case queries, keys and values are the same tensor, i.e., the output of the Bi-LSTM.

Comment: I am new to attention, a bit confused about after putting the output of the lstm into the multiheadattention class and what do we do about the output of the attnetion layer?